# Antonym of "exodus"

Tags: single-word-requests, antonyms

5PM. There's a mass exodus out of the city as people depart for home. What word describes the migration in the other direction -- A mass *arrival* of people? As far as I know, there isn't a word like "introdus".

Perhaps a word like "intrution"?

Comment: You need a reverse diaspora.

Comment: If *exo-* means "outward" and *endo-* means "inward"… (How I wish English worked this way more often…)

Comment: or reverse exodus!

Comment: @Oldcat So it’s down to *aropsaid* versus *sudoxe* then. Hm, I still think I like the first one better.

Comment: While "influx" is the word that comes most readily to mind, one should remember that "exodus" sometimes has a connotation of being expelled or cast out or fleeing onerous conditions, so a word which implies being welcomed or enticed to enter/return might be more appropriate in some circumstances.  (I don't have any such words in mind, though.)

Comment: Agree with @HotLicks that exodus implies refugee status.  Influx of refugees?  Also, "deluge" works; flood terminology is a great metaphor to communicate "more coming in than expected."

Answer (score 69, accepted):

Consider "influx":

World English Dictionary
— n
1.  the arrival or entry of many people or things

Answer (score 22):

Though I have not been able to find this anywhere quoted as an antonym, I feel fairly sure the modern word, in current use would be **influx**.

Oxford Dictionaries provides its literal meaning to do with an inflow of water into a lake, secondary significance. Its first meaning, according to OD is: *an arrival or entry of large numbers of people or things. e.g 'a massive influx of tourists'*

Its etymology is late 16th century (denoting an inflow of liquid, gas, or light) from Latin *influxus,* from *influere* flow in (see INFLUENCE).

Answer (score 13):

Here's a more literal antonym:
Exodus, or Exodos, is Greek for exit. So an antonym could be entrance: είσοδος or eisodos.

Comment: This is fantastic. Eisodus was what I was looking for.

Comment: This is not an English word. If you wanted a Greek word, @BBON, you should help get [this site off the ground](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/60122/classical-greek-language)

Answer (score 6):

I've looked up larithmics terms and they refer to it as surges in population

Inrush as in "The inrush of Settlers"

The winning of the West / by Theodore Roosevelt. ... v.4. Roosevelt, Theodore, 1858-1919.

Comment: A *surge in population* would tend to be more permanent than a mass arrival at 9am prior to a mass departure at 5pm [as given in the question] though?

Comment: It has been used with respect to emergency planning in governmental literature.   What do you think of inrush?  I have yet to find it associated with population increase but it does mean an inflow, a crowding, or a flooding in.

Comment: @AndrewLeach It seems perfectly reasonable that an inrush could be followed by an outrush.

Answer (score 2):

Describing the context will be helpful. Are you talking about something that is happening routinely/repeatedly (e.g. people coming back from holidays) or some sudden/one-time event (e.g. refugees)? If it's the former "influx" as mentioned above would be adequate. In the latter case I would, perhaps, use "a flood of new arrivals" if dramatic effect is sought.

Answer (score 1):

I know "introitus" does have a different meaning, but, perhaps it could convey the meaning required for the opposite of exodus? Then there is insodus.

Comment: Really? Introitus: *entering the vaginal opening*. I think not, and the urban dictionary entry for "insodus" is very weak since 2006: 6 upvotes and 2 downvotes.

Answer (score 1):

Exodus means to 'come out of', as to emigrate/emigration. Immigrate/immigration means 'going into' thus a good antonym for exodus.